# fluids simulation : do not fill domain?

Tags: fluid-simulation

I'm trying to generate a realistic rain using fluid simulation (I need realistic droplets).

I was wondering if it is possible to "emit" fluid from my inflow objects **without** having it filling its domain; like you can kill particles when it touch a surface.

I know I could make a bigger domain but this costs a lot in performance.
My idea is that if I could ignore the "filling", the performance could be better and the cache would be lighter.

Possible ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I just found out that this is what **outflows** are for.